Massive problems with Xubuntu and Logitech Unifying receiver
Recently, I installed Xubuntu 24.04 LTS on my old Lenovo Mii Mix 310 (Atom based Notebook), and everything works fine since I recently bought a Logitec M705 Wireless mouse which totally causes trouble on that PC which is not there in the parallely installed Windows 10 version on the same hardware:
1.) When the unifying receiver is plugged into the USB port on the left side of the device (it only has two USB ports), Xubuntu completely freezes during startup. When the device is connected on the right hand side however, the system boots up flawlessly and the mouse is usable
2.) The unifying receiver interferes with the energy display of XCFE in a way as it seems to present a second energy control (the one of the battery og the mouse attached), and in some cases, it does not display the battery status of the notebook anymore, which is the only energy level that really matters to me. In the Power Manager window, I can see the Marathon mouse as well as the battery and the line power, but sometimes the internal battery is missing. This is not reproducable upon every boot, but when it happens, I cannot see the state of the internal battery anymore.
Is there any possibility to improve the support for the Logitech Unifying receiver?

Good point @guiverc, I have added that information to my question - Xubuntu 24.04 LTS is installed
